# How to filter json with jq, if keys has dynamic value

Tags: json, key, jq

i have json:

```
    {
   "error": 0,
   "descErr": "Ok",
   "seqNumber": 0,
   "data": {
      "events": [],
      "devices": {
         "aaa1234a": {
            "deviceType": "aaa",
            "ip": "192.168.1.4",
            "otherInformation": "blabla4"
            },
         "aaa1235a": {
            "deviceType": "aaa",
            "ip": "192.168.1.5",
            "otherInformation": "blabla5"
            },
        "aaa1236a": {
            "deviceType": "aaa",
            "ip": "192.168.1.6",
            "otherInformation": "blabla6"
            }
         }
    }
}
```

and want to get only device name (into json look like aaa1234a), `ip` and `otherInformation` with **jq**.
i need a result:

```
"aaa1234a": {
            "ip": "192.168.1.4",
            "otherInformation": "blabla4"
            },
"aaa1235a": {
            "ip": "192.168.1.5",
            "otherInformation": "blabla5"
            },
"aaa1236a": {
            "ip": "192.168.1.6",
            "otherInformation": "blabla6"
            }
```

How is filtering this json with jq, if device name i do not know, but look like "aaa1234a", where aaa - type device and last "a" - model device - 1234 - dynamic name

Comment: What's wrong with `jq '.data.devices'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jqplay.org/s/n1kf-19yFT

With the input

```
{
   "error": 0,
   "descErr": "Ok",
   "seqNumber": 0,
   "data": {
      "events": [],
      "devices": {
         "aaa1234a": {
            "deviceType": "aaa",
            "ip": "192.168.1.4",
            "otherInformation": "blabla4"
            },
         "aaa1235a": {
            "deviceType": "aaa",
            "ip": "192.168.1.5",
            "otherInformation": "blabla5"
            },
        "aaa1236a": {
            "deviceType": "aaa",
            "ip": "192.168.1.6",
            "otherInformation": "blabla6"
            }
         }
    }
}
```

When I execute the query

`.data.devices | to_entries | map({key, value: {ip: .value.ip, otherInformation: .value.otherInformation}}) | from_entries`

I've got the output

```
{
  "aaa1234a": {
    "ip": "192.168.1.4",
    "otherInformation": "blabla4"
  },
  "aaa1235a": {
    "ip": "192.168.1.5",
    "otherInformation": "blabla5"
  },
  "aaa1236a": {
    "ip": "192.168.1.6",
    "otherInformation": "blabla6"
  }
}
```

Is this what you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

To select the keys matching the regex pattern "^aaa.*a$", you could write:

```
.devices | with_entries(select(.key|test("^aaa.*a$")))
```

Similarly, if you wanted to retain the original structure:

```
.data.devices |= with_entries(select(.key|test("^aaa.*a$")))
```